# Is there any negation logics for expressions in ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I want to know whether it is possible to negate the expression in ballerina like

> (not expression)

or

> (!expression)

Comment: Did you try `!`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could simply use (!expression).

```
boolean test = true;

if (!test){
    io:println(test);
} else {
    io:println(!test);
}
```